# Why doesn't left join elimination work properly for large queries?

Tags: postgresql

Have discovered kind of unexpected behaviour of query planner:

```sql
create table t1 (c1 integer primary key, c2 varchar(255));
create table t2 (c1 integer primary key, c2 varchar(255));
create table t3 (c1 integer primary key, c2 varchar(255));
create table t4 (c1 integer primary key, c2 varchar(255));
create table t5 (c1 integer primary key, c2 varchar(255));
create table t6 (c1 integer primary key, c2 varchar(255));
create table t7 (c1 integer primary key, c2 varchar(255));
create table t8 (c1 integer primary key, c2 varchar(255));
create table t9 (c1 integer primary key, c2 varchar(255));
create table t10 (c1 integer primary key, c2 varchar(255));
create table t11 (c1 integer primary key, c2 varchar(255));
create table t12 (c1 integer primary key, c2 varchar(255));
create table t13 (c1 integer primary key, c2 varchar(255));
create table t14 (c1 integer primary key, c2 varchar(255));
create table t15 (c1 integer primary key, c2 varchar(255));
create table t16 (c1 integer primary key, c2 varchar(255));
create table t17 (c1 integer primary key, c2 varchar(255));
create table t18 (c1 integer primary key, c2 varchar(255));
create table t19 (c1 integer primary key, c2 varchar(255));
create table t20 (c1 integer primary key, c2 varchar(255));
```

for the query like:

```sql
select t1.c1
from t1
         left join t2 on t1.c1 = t2.c1
         left join t3 on t1.c1 = t3.c1
         left join t4 on t1.c1 = t4.c1
         left join t5 on t1.c1 = t5.c1
         left join t6 on t1.c1 = t6.c1
         left join t7 on t1.c1 = t7.c1
         left join t8 on t1.c1 = t8.c1
         left join t9 on t1.c1 = t9.c1
         left join t10 on t1.c1 = t10.c1
         left join t11 on t1.c1 = t11.c1
         left join t12 on t1.c1 = t12.c1
         left join t13 on t1.c1 = t13.c1
         left join t14 on t1.c1 = t14.c1
         left join t15 on t1.c1 = t15.c1
         left join t16 on t1.c1 = t16.c1
         left join t17 on t1.c1 = t17.c1
         left join t18 on t1.c1 = t18.c1
         left join t19 on t1.c1 = t19.c1
         left join t20 on t1.c1 = t20.c1
         inner join t1 tt on tt.c1 = t2.c1
where t20.c2 = '1';
```

PostgreSQL generates following bizarre query plan:

```sql
Nested Loop  (cost=25.06..37.32 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.089..0.162 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=24.91..37.07 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.067..0.120 rows=0 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (t1.c1 = t20.c1)
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=13.15..24.93 rows=140 width=8) (never executed)
              Hash Cond: (t1.c1 = t2.c1)
              ->  Seq Scan on t1  (cost=0.00..11.40 rows=140 width=4) (never executed)
              ->  Hash  (cost=11.40..11.40 rows=140 width=4) (never executed)
                    ->  Seq Scan on t2  (cost=0.00..11.40 rows=140 width=4) (never executed)
        ->  Hash  (cost=11.75..11.75 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.041..0.072 rows=0 loops=1)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8kB
              ->  Seq Scan on t20  (cost=0.00..11.75 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.018..0.028 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Filter: ((c2)::text = '1'::text)
  ->  Index Only Scan using t1_pkey on t1 tt  (cost=0.14..0.25 rows=1 width=4) (never executed)
        Index Cond: (c1 = t1.c1)
        Heap Fetches: 0
```

However, for semantically equivalent query:

```sql
select t1.c1
from t1
         left join t2 on t1.c1 = t2.c1
--         left join t3 on t1.c1 = t3.c1
--         left join t4 on t1.c1 = t4.c1
--         left join t5 on t1.c1 = t5.c1
--         left join t6 on t1.c1 = t6.c1
--         left join t7 on t1.c1 = t7.c1
--         left join t8 on t1.c1 = t8.c1
--         left join t9 on t1.c1 = t9.c1
--         left join t10 on t1.c1 = t10.c1
--        left join t11 on t1.c1 = t11.c1
--        left join t12 on t1.c1 = t12.c1
--        left join t13 on t1.c1 = t13.c1
--        left join t14 on t1.c1 = t14.c1
--        left join t15 on t1.c1 = t15.c1
--         left join t16 on t1.c1 = t16.c1
--         left join t17 on t1.c1 = t17.c1
--         left join t18 on t1.c1 = t18.c1
--        left join t19 on t1.c1 = t19.c1
         left join t20 on t1.c1 = t20.c1
         inner join t1 tt on tt.c1 = t2.c1
where t20.c2 = '1'
```

the query plan looks "much better":

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..14.40 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.056..0.108 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.14..14.14 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.035..0.066 rows=0 loops=1)
        ->  Seq Scan on t20  (cost=0.00..11.75 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.015..0.026 rows=0 loops=1)
              Filter: ((c2)::text = '1'::text)
        ->  Index Only Scan using t2_pkey on t2  (cost=0.14..2.36 rows=1 width=4) (never executed)
              Index Cond: (c1 = t20.c1)
              Heap Fetches: 0
  ->  Index Only Scan using t1_pkey on t1 tt  (cost=0.14..0.25 rows=1 width=4) (never executed)
        Index Cond: ((c1 = t2.c1) AND (c1 IS NOT NULL))
        Heap Fetches: 0
```

after some research I have found that `join_collapse_limit`/`from_collapse_limit` settings somehow influence on query planner, but the problem is the idea of setting those values too high (my estimation is `30` for particular ORM application) seems to be wrong. Is there other option?

Comment: You either have to increase `join_collapse_limit` and have the optimizer think harder, or (recommended) write better queries.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe shouldn't planner eliminate superfluous joins prior making decision that query contains too many joins? I do see it eliminates them but that happens too late.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the parameter.

Comment: How is supposed to decide which joins are superfluous, without first analyzing them?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe m.b. you are right, but that is how documentation is written (it is primarily about join order): I do not see a direct correlation between amount of joins in the query and the amount of permutations planner should check prior choosing "optimal" plan: it should not consider some permutations at all

Comment: @jjanes that is simple: if join neither increase nor reduce row count (i.e. outer join on unique column) and does not participate in projection and selection it could be eliminated.

Comment: But for that PostgreSQL has to know that it should start with the last table, right?

Comment: Not at all, just blindly eliminate everything that meats criteria, and after that start thinking about optimal path: there is no option when starting with superfluous row source may somehow improve query plan.

Comment: There are thousands of things which can be done which are each simple individually but become a problem collectively.  That is why the collapse limit exists.  Why should your favorite one be exempted from the collapse limit, rather than someone else's favorite one?

Answer (score 2):

Well, below is what I have "learned" after reading PostgreSQL source code (the part about `semantic equivalence` of SQL queries was not a part of my learning curve and it is actually perfectly described in [cost based query transformations concept](https://docplayer.net/64198129-Cost-based-query-transformations-concept-and-analysis-using-trace.html))

The main idea of `semantic equivalence` of SQL queries is that we may transform some SQL queries to another form, which produces the same results and at the same time it is more convenient for query planner (read: more convenient for developers who have designed the query planner), for example the query:

```sql
select t1.c1
from t1
         inner join t2 on t1.c1 = t2.c1
where t2.c2 = '1';
```

is `semantically equivalent` to the following "flattened" form:

```sql
select t1.c1
from t1,
     t2
where t1.c1 = t2.c1
  and t2.c2 = '1';
```

However, from the perspective of a person, who have written the first query, those queries might seem different (at least, some of my colleagues do think so: *"I have rewritten query to use explicit joins and now it is much faster"*):

- in first case we might think we are ordering db engine to read all rows from `t1` first and than join result with `t2`
- in the second case we "intuitively" understand that db engine is free to choose another plan

PostgreSQL planner tends to not honour developer's opinion and tries to transform explicit joins (both `inner` and `outer` - unlike Oracle, PostgreSQL does not provide [special SQL-syntax for outer join](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/post/outerjoins-in-oracle), however, internal representation seems to be similar) to flattened form - at this stage PostgreSQL does not take into account any information about DB tables (nullability, uniqueness, existence of foreign keys etc): it just transforms query into some kind of canonical form. Thereafter planner encounters a real challenge: it needs to build a query plan, and the problem is that is not always "possible" to build "optimal" plan without extra assumptions, for example, PostgreSQL fails to build plan for the following query:

```sql
set geqo = off;

select t1.c1
from t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10,
     t11, t12, t13, t14, t15, t16, t17, t18,
     t19, t20, t1 tt
where t20.c2 = '1' and t1.c1 = t2.c1
  and t1.c1 = t3.c1 and t1.c1 = t4.c1
  and t1.c1 = t5.c1 and t1.c1 = t6.c1
  and t1.c1 = t7.c1 and t1.c1 = t8.c1
  and t1.c1 = t9.c1 and t1.c1 = t10.c1
  and t1.c1 = t11.c1 and t1.c1 = t12.c1
  and t1.c1 = t13.c1 and t1.c1 = t14.c1
  and t1.c1 = t15.c1 and t1.c1 = t16.c1
  and t1.c1 = t17.c1 and t1.c1 = t18.c1
  and t1.c1 = t19.c1 and t1.c1 = t20.c1
  and tt.c1 = t2.c1;
```

*"fails to build plan" there means PostgreSQL starts consuming terabytes of memory, zillions of CPU cycles and finally gets killed by OOM-killer, and, unfortunately, immediately starts recovering DB (here I have learned that the idea of setting `geqo` to `off` or setting `geqo_threshold` to value greater than `~13-14` seems not to be wise).*

Prior to planning resulting "flattened" query PostgreSQL also tries to perform some trivial query transformations, one of them is elimination of superfluous outer joins, which I actually interested in, however, the most of useful transformations described in [cost based query transformations concept](https://docplayer.net/64198129-Cost-based-query-transformations-concept-and-analysis-using-trace.html) are not implemented: [Removing INNER JOINs](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/VisenaEmail.2b.7dfa64bdab147c49.1600d1d9df0@tc7-visena#).

What is the role of `join_collapse_limit` setting there?

When PostgreSQL is trying to rewrite query containing explicit joins into "flattened" form, it starts suspecting that if query contains too many tables planner most probably will fail to build "optimal" plan (there is an option to switch to `geqo` mode, which is fast in planning, but may produce suboptimal plans), however, instead of relying on `geqo` planner is doing following: it distributes "flattened" joins among groups/clusters of size not exceeding `join_collapse_limit` and believes that it is possible to solve planning problem for each group/cluster individually.

`join_collapse_limit` setting obviously does not have any effect for already "flattened" queries, and here I failed to understand the reason why it was introduced:

- PostgreSQL does not honour initial query structure, even if developer have provided useful "hints" (parenthesis, lateral joins, etc), but believes it is able to construct something reliable if it takes advantage of `divide and conquer` approach (that seems to be the reason of why documentation highlights `join_collapse_limit=1` case only)
- my colleagues, me and, no doubts, everybody, who have previous `Oracle` experience, do not use explicit joins when writing SQL-queries: basically, "explicit joins style" is less convenient, however, various ORMs actually tend to prefer explicit joins - that is much simpler to generate queries using this style.
- I'm actually forced to use explicit outer joins because both SQL standard and PostgreSQL do not provide another syntax, however in that case I face with non-obvious behaviour from PostgreSQL side, and the controversial part there is: although outer joins are much more lightweight from query planning perspective (i.e. since they are more restrictive in sense of allowed permutations, planner ultimately needs to check less permutations, also, there is a chance to eliminate superfluous outer joins), PostgreSQL planner mistakenly complicates execution plans for such queries.

So, based on arguments provided above, I would say that in general case it is not possible to understand whether SQL query contains explicit joins intentionally or not, and in my opinion the `join_collapse_limit` setting does not make sense at all.

Comment: " "explicit joins style" is less convenient" what? You Oracle people are definitely living on a different planet than the rest of the world.