# Can this subquery be optimized by a join? - Even without foreignkeys?

Tags: postgresql, performance

I have a table with two important columns: `entity` and `enabled`. The idea is that entities are "unique groups" where all rows with the same `entity` belong to the same "item".

I wish to find all rows, which belong to an `entity` that contains no `enabled` row. So entities where all lines are "disabled".

There are no foreign keys defined. `entity` is just an arbitrary identifier but can also be null where they belong to the main group. So there is no main element to point to.

The following query works:

```
SELECT * 
FROM public.my_list
WHERE id not in (
    SELECT l.id
    FROM public.my_list as l
    INNER JOIN public.my_list as ol 
    ON ol.entity=l.entity 
    AND ol.enabled=true
);
```

This uses an `inner join` inside a subquery, which feels like a lot of redundancy. Could this be optimized? Considering the table has close to a million entries, and the returned set will be sizeable (like few 100 000).

(I know the `select` by itself is terrible, but this is further filtered in the customer dataset, and leads to a `delete`.)

Comment: [Don't use NOT IN](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_NOT_IN). `select * from my_list ml where not exists(select * from my_list ml2 where ml.entity = ml2.entity and ml2.enabled = true)` or `select * from (select id, entity, first_value(enabled) over (partition by entity order by enabled desc) as enabled from my_list) q where enabled = false`

Comment: This looks like the dreaded [entity-attribute-value design](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/entity-attribute-value-eav-design-in-postgresql-dont-do-it/), so there is probably no way to query it efficiently.

Comment: a join is only noticeable faster, of the table is big, else ou will not notice it

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe just for my own understanding (I can't redesign the whole company's application by myself...), it is used as a rudimentary "version control"/"audit", each update instead gives a new entry and makes the old entry "inactive". That's different from eav right?

Comment: That doesn't sound like classical EAV, so that may be fine - I don't know the data model. It was the strange self-join that made me wonder about the data model.

Answer (score 3):

Your current solution performs terribly for two reasons:

1. **`NOT IN` is the worst** option when paired with a subquery.
   Plus, it introduces traps for null values:

   - Your subquery excludes all rows with a null value in one of the columns `(entity, enabled)`. Thereby *including* the entity in the result.
   - Also, if the subquery returns any null values the entity is also not excluded, i.e. *included*.

   Don't go there.
2. Your subquery joins every row with every row (incl. itself) in the set of rows with the same entity, basically a Cartesian product scaling with **O(N²)**. With more than a few rows for the same entity, performance deteriorates quickly.

Instead, use one of the more efficient and predictable query techniques. See:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19364694/939860)

With `NOT EXISTS`, similar to what [Andrey](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/271578/andrey-b-panfilov) commented:

```
SELECT *
FROM   my_list l
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM my_list l2
   WHERE  l2.entity = l.entity
   AND    l2.enabled
   );
```

Or with `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL`:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM   my_list l
LEFT   JOIN my_list l2 ON l2.entity = l.entity
                      AND l2.enabled
WHERE  l2.entity IS NULL;
```

If [Laurenz](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/176905/laurenz-albe) is right, and this is an EAV design, you are in a tight spot to begin with.

[Foreign key constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) enforce referential integrity, but have no influence on the performance of this `SELECT` query.

Comment: "`NOT IN` is the worst option when paired with a subquery" why? Apart from the null problem, it should optimize the same as a `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: @Charlieface No, there is a logical difference, that (among other things) leads to worse performance.

Comment: I fail to see how there can be a logical difference if neither side is nullable.

Comment: But there is if either side is nullable. Detailed rationale [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_NOT_IN).

Comment: I know that, that wasn't what I asked. I asked if there were any *other* issues. You said "NOT IN is the worst option when paired with a subquery. Plus, it introduces traps for null values." which implies there is a difference *aside* from the null issue. Please explain.

Comment: It's bad for performance **and** it regularly breaks queries if null values are involved.

Comment: I'm going round in circles. If neither column is nullable (ie nulls are **not allowed** not just not present), then how can it break or be a perf issue? I'm not disagreeing that it's best avoided because of this issue (you might end up using it accidentally on a nullable column), but I don't see how there can be any other issue.

Comment: A subquery can produce null values even from `NOT NULL` columns (think of outer joins, ...). To optimize performance, Postgres would have to inspect involved table definitions and the structure of the subquery before proceeding, just to give you what `NOT EXISTS` can give you without all that. I assume that's why nobody bothers to put lipstick on the "NOT IN" pig.

Comment: @Charlieface my understanding is following: PostgreSQL is required to satisfy some obvious concepts from SQL Standard, like not in (null) is null, so in general, that is required to scan corresponding rows source fully in order to understand whether there are nulls or not. You are insisting that it is actually not required since you are querying PK, that is, obviously correct (and does work in Oracle, for example), however PostgreSQL team has another opinion on that, please check, for example, discussion under https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/328208/271578

Comment: basically, the module (code) in PostgreSQL responsible for planning does known nothing about whether you are querying `not null` column or not. For example, when we were migrating DB from Oracle to PostgreSQL we were rewriting **correct** NON IN queries into NOT EXISTS form just because PostgreSQL was failing to infer information about PK.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Yes interesting, that appears to be correct from a little testing I did. SQL Server definitely does do such analysis, so `NOT IN` on non-null columns is the same as a `NOT EXISTS` there. I agree it should obviously still be avoided, you never know when someone might change a column definition or mistakenly do the same on a different column.